# Vaadin update from 14.x to 14.7.x causing layout problems. Is there any best practice?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

is there any best practice how to update from Vaadin 14.4.x to Vaadin 14.6 or Vaadin 14.7?
Just updating the dependency's will cause that fonts do not look same anymore.
Also the switch to dark mode also does nor work anymore (https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/toggle-dark-theme).

As soon as I switch back to 14.4.x all works again.

I am using Java only no Spring.

Do I need to delete any cache or something? I deleted the frontend folder already, but that does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Did you also delete package*, webpack* and node_modules?

Comment: Thank you Simon, I have deleted node_modules. wepack and package do not exist. But I still have the same problem. Strange is, it only occures when updating to a version higher then 14.4.0. Is there an other cache or temporary files I may need to clean / delete?

Comment: No one any idea? I tried to copy parts of the code into a new project and fonts, switch to dark mode, works again. But that means my old project cant be used anymore. No idea which cache or frontend or any other file is causing it...

Comment: When you say `updating to a version higher then 14.4.0` is that also a problem for 14.4.10 or 14.5.0 as you only name 14.6 and 14.7. CustomTheme did come in 14.6, but it shouldn't change anything for the existing themes.